# High power constant current source

Tags: led, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, led-driver, constant-current

I want to make a high power flashlight with a 10 W (3.3 V 3 A white) LED in it, its a single LED and 2 Li-ion batteries in series.

The problem is that I can't find a good LED driver to have a relatively good efficiency.

Also even if I wanted to do, it's getting really hot (LED driver). So I don't think a linear voltage regulator design works, design with 2 BJT transistors (I guess it's a current mirror like) will not work either.

Is there any design that maybe uses SMPs? Preferably with a NE555 or anything common.
If you know anything that help me please send me the schematics for it.

Comment: What is supply voltage? The Led is just one or more? If more they are connected in series?

Comment: Please edit that information into the question body. What you need is a constant current buck converter.

Comment: Commonly, a "switched" - in comparison to a linear - approach is employed when efficiency or high current capability is necessary.

Comment: and that's why i need it

Comment: So, you know what you need. What's stopping you?

Comment: How much efficiency is good efficiency? I think basically all of them are higher than 80%, and the highest numbers I've seen for these types of converters were around 97% (that was an advertisement for some company's ultra-high-efficiency converters)

Comment: I know LT makes some one-chip switching regulators (just add inductor) for constant-current LED drive. There are probably some from Maxim and TI as well, if LT is too expensive for you (and it very well could be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two li-ions in series the linear supply would have terrible efficiency.
Much better would be 4 Ni-MH in series so you get 4-5V power supply (according state of discharge).
At 5V supply there will be about 66% efficiency.
At 4V supply about 82%.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy9GuQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is a linear regulator which is inherently going to have lower efficiency than a switching regulator. If you are chasing efficiency you really need a switching regulator.

Comment: true, i'm okay with linear only thing is that making that much waste power is going to make flash light unconfortably hot, more than it is. so, what im looking for is enough efficency to not burning my self.

Comment: @user253751 switching regulator efficiency isn't *inherently* better. There are circumstances where a linear regulator can be highly efficient (85-95%) and then it takes a very careful switching design to do better (meaning you can't just count on the switcher being **inherently** better).

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, a linear regulator can have high efficiency if it's not actually regulating very much...

Comment: @user253751, Even with reasonable currents (100's of mA) it's not hard to find scenarios where the LDO meets or beats the switcher efficiency. As long as \$V_{out}/V_{in}\$ is above 85 or 90% you're getting in the range of switcher efficiency. (And at low currents it's easy to win because switchers usually get very inefficient at low current)